# expand on click function to sidecaegorylist in bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

i am trying to come up with a way of displaying a lot of categories in side list.

The only way i can see as a usable way instead of those annoying fly out menus, is to expand categories upon clicking on parent category.

support have provided a js to display when hover over parent, but want it to expand and close on click, and to close upon another parent is clicked.

```
<style>
.SideCategoryListClassic ul li ul li {
display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li')
.hover(function(){$(this).children('ul').children().slideDown()},
function(){$(this).children('ul').children().slideUp()});
</script>
```

Hope someone can share some light on this.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to do this by just adding a class when a parent is clicked.

```
$('.SideCategoryListClassic li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //This prevents clicking causing the user to actually go to the link they clicked on
  $('.SideCategoryListClassic li ul').removeClass('active'); //Removes active class from other submenus
  $(this).find('ul').slideDown(); //Adds active class to the submenu of the parent you just clicked on
});
```

then your css

```
.SideCategoryListClassic li ul {display:none}
.SideCategoryListClassic li ul.active {display:block;}
```